# CSS3 - Animate background image filter

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out a solution to animate my site's background filter.
I want it to go from sharp to blur on page load, which I know how to do, but as my background is on the `body`, adding a filter would affect everything.

```
body {
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url("bg_beach.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I've tried to add a new div for the background, but just messed everything up
Maybe there would be a way with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery won't help here. You are dealing with CSS only.
If adding a new DIV for you background image messes things up for you, try again. This time kick it out of the document flow like this:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image:url("bg_beach.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#main {
    position: relative;
}
```

The `top`, `bottom`, `right`, `left` properties set to `0` act as 100% width/height.   Position `absolute` keeps the DIV out of your other elements layout flow.

Your HTML would look like:

```
<body>
    <div class="mydiv"></div>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- page content here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I did it exactly like that. Everything gets under the background, except my title that fades in on page load. I'd give you a link, but the site is only local right now.

Comment: See my edit. Add `position:relative` to the `#main` DIV where your content goes. http://jsfiddle.net/CAV8f/